# javascript, how to get the value from a text area on click?

Tags: javascript, forms

i have a input area and a button like this:

```
<input type="text" name="text_name" id="txt_name" size="30" maxlength="70">
<input type=button id="btnPublishAction" onclick="publishFeed()" value="Yeah" style="margin: 5px 0;" />
```

and a function like this:

```
    name = oForm.elements["text_name"].value;

    function publishFeed() {
var act = new gigya.services.socialize.UserAction();        
act.setUserMessage(name);
act.setLinkBack("http://www.xxx.com");      
act.setTitle("Check me out!");      
act.setDescription("This is my Profile"); 
act.addMediaItem( { 
    src: '<?php echo $photoDiv; ?>',
    href: 'http://www.exploretalent.com/<?php echo $_SESSION['talent_username'];?>',
    type: 'image'
});
var params = 
    {
        userAction:act, 
        scope: 'internal',
        privacy: 'public',
        callback:publishAction_callback
    };
gigya.services.socialize.publishUserAction(conf, params);
}
```

what i am trying to do is when i click `Yeah` the value from the `text_name` to be set into `act.setUserMessage(name);` where `name = oForm.elements["text_name"].value;`.

i found this syntax `name = oForm.elements["text_name"].value;` but not sure if that works

any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `oForm` is a reference to a form on your page.  And assuming your textarea is contained in that form.  And assuming your textarea has a name attribute of "text_name", then yes, that should work.  Just drop that line of code into your function as the first line.

```
function publishFeed() {
    var name = oForm.elements["text_name"].value;
    var act = new gigya.services.socialize.UserAction();        
    act.setUserMessage(name);
    ...
}
```

With `name = ...` above the function, the `name` variable is not updated when the text changes.  You want to set the value of that variable within your function so that you are getting the current text.

**Edit:** If you don't want to use a form on your page, then give your textarea an id and access it via that id:

```
<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
```

Here's the update JavaScript:

```
function publishFeed() {
    var name = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;
    var act = new gigya.services.socialize.UserAction();        
    act.setUserMessage(name);
    ...
}
```

Comment: dont i need a form to pass a get to that script? im just a bitconfuse

Comment: You didn't mention that you don't have a form.  Give your textarea an id and access it with `document.getElementById("myTextAreaId")`.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

try using `name = document.getElementById("txt_name").value`